# Laravel frontend scaffolding

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning laravel framework. I followed the installation steps. Now I am installing Bootstrap and Vue scaffolding. Referring to this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend).

I have run the cmd `composer require laravel/ui --dev`. Followed I run the following commands as they said.

```
// Generate basic scaffolding...
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui react

// Generate login / registration scaffolding...
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

`php artisan ui vue --auth` this command installs files/folders successfully. Later when I run `php artisan ui react --auth` this command asks

```
The [auth/login.blade.php] view already exists. Do you want to replace it? (yes/no) [no]:
```

Why this asks for multiple auth files? What should be the answer?

Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: First in what front end are you want to develop?
bootstrap or vue or react ?

Comment: If you want to go with just bootstrap then install it only not all the things.

Comment: And the question is asked to you because you already created one scaffholding with vue and bootstrap and again if you try to create it. It will asked you the question to remove the existing one.

Comment: bootstrap is for css and vue is for js..right , so i will need both i guess. I don't know about vue and react. Do I have to install vue or react ? or installing bootstrap by `composer require laravel/ui --dev` this command is enough. then I don't have to run that 4 commands afterwords. Please let me know this is right or not

Comment: Decide if you want to use either Vue _or_ React. Then run either `php artisan ui vue --auth` _or_ `php artisan ui react --auth`

Comment: vue and react is a frontend framework you don't need it to run the command untill you want to work in one of them. just 'php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` is enough after then run the `npm install` and `npm run dev` to get your bootstrap and css ready to use.